# How to make custom validation_step in tensorflow 2 Tensorflow 2 / Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a question regarding the validation Data.
I have this neural network and I divided my data into train_generator, val_generator, test_generator.

I made a custom model with a custom fit.

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
     def __init__(self):
     def __call__(.....)
     def train_step(....)
```

then I have:

```
 train_generator = DataGenerator(....)
 val_generator = DataGenerator(....)
 test_generator = DataGenerator(....)
```

then :

```
 model = MyModel()
 model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(clipnorm=5.),
               metrics=["accuracy"])
 model.fit(train_generator, validation_data = val_generator, epochs=40)
```

ok and the program gives me no errors
But my question is : how can I know what happens with my validation_data ?
Is it processed the same way as the train_data ( train_generator ) in the train_step function ?
Or do I need to specify how to process the validation data ?

If it helps I will also live MyModel class

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel2, self).__init__()
    self.dec2 = Decoder2()

def __call__(self, y_hat, **kwargs): 

    print(y_hat.shape)

    z_hat = self.dec2(y_hat)
    return z_hat

def train_step(self, dataset): 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        y_hat = dataset[0]
        z_true = dataset[1]

        z_pred = self(y_hat, training=True)

        #print("This is z_true : ", z_true.shape)
        #print("This is z_pred : ", z_pred.shape)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(tf.cast(z_pred, tf.float64) - tf.cast(z_true, tf.float64)))
        print("loss: ", loss)
        global_loss.append(loss)

    # Compute gradients. TRE SA FAC GRADIENT CLIPPING
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(z_true, z_pred)
    # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to add a test_step(self, data) function to your MyModel class as you can see it here: [Providing your own evaluation step](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit#providing_your_own_evaluation_step)